# Use Test button in API Gateway console with specific lambda version

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I have an API Gateway resource that points to a specific version of lambda:

Foo-LambdaFunction7804AD21-1LLYB0GTDYURR:1

I use AWS API Gateway web UI navigate to the resource, then "test" section. I click "Test" and get back:

```
Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function
```

If I point to a lambda ARN without a version, i.e.
`Foo-LambdaFunction7804AD21-1LLYB0GTDYURR`
then it works as expected.

Does "Test" page of the AWS UI console has a different resource id and requires different resource-based policy statement?

Answer (score 0):

I had to give API Gateway's execution role a permission to call `Foo-LambdaFunction7804AD21-1LLYB0GTDYURR:1` lambda version.